# Parsing a List of Tweets in Order to Utlize Gensim Word2Vec

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, topic-modeling

I'm working on an NLP problem and my goal is to be able to pass my data into sklearn's algos after having used Word2Vec via Python's Gensim Library. The underlying problem I am trying to solve is binary classification of a series of tweets. To do so I am modifying the code in [this](https://github.com/halidebey/PyCon2018/blob/master/analysis.py) git repo.

Here is part of the code relating to tokenization:

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
input_file["tokens"] = input_file["text"].apply(tokenizer.tokenize)
all_words = [word for tokens in input_file["tokens"] for word in tokens]
sentence_lengths = [len(tokens) for tokens in input_file["tokens"]]
vocabulary = sorted(set(all_words))
```

Now here is the part where I use Gensim's sklearn-api to try to vectorize my tweets:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from gensim.test.utils import common_texts
from gensim.sklearn_api import W2VTransformer
text = input_file["text"].tolist()
labels = input_file["label"].tolist()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(text, labels, test_size=0.2,random_state=40)
model = W2VTransformer(size=10, min_count=1, seed=1)
X_train_w2v = model.fit(common_texts).transform(X_train)
```

This results in the following error:

```
KeyError: "word 'Great seeing you again, don't be a stranger!' not in vocabulary"
```

It seems that part of the issue is that Gensim is expecting to be fed one word at a time and instead it is getting entire tweets.

X_train is of type list, here are the first three elements of the list:

```
["Great seeing you again, don't be a stranger!",
 "Beautiful day here in sunny Prague. Not a cloud in the sky",
 " pfft! i wish I had a laptop like that"]
```

**Update**

In order to remedy this, I have tried the following:

```
X_train_list = []
for sentence in X_train:
word_list = sentence.split(' ')
while("" in word_list): 
    word_list.remove("") 
X_train_list.append(word_list)
model = W2VTransformer(size=10, min_count=1, seed=1)
X_train_tfidf = model.fit(common_texts).transform(X_train_list)
```

This produces the following error:

```
KeyError: "word 'here' not in vocabulary"
```

To be honest, this one blows my mind! How a common word like 'here' is not in the vocabulary is beyond me. Also wondering if tweets with stray letters will throwing errors, I imagine the weird jumbles of letters that often pass for words will cause similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

The Gensim model indeed expects a list of word-lists as input instead of just a list of sentences. Your `X_train` should look like this:

```
[["Great", "seeing", "you", "again", "..."], 
["Beautiful", "day", "..."], 
...
]
```

**Update:** As for the new part of your question the problem is that `common_texts` is a tiny dataset consisting of only 9 sentences so it is not so surprising that the vocabulary is very small. Try training on a bigger dataset before using `transform`. In your case you can probably find a dataset of tweets to train on. You could also consider using FastText if you want to get vectors for out-of-vocabulary words.

Comment: You are correct, this is reflected in the update I have made.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include your new question.